# Plural of single letter variables

Tags: technical-writing, punctuation

Excuse me if I am on the wrong StackExchange site. I write about [Physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/) in [English](https://english.stackexchange.com/) and [typeset](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/) that with [LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/).

So I have a variable *c*, and there are two of them in the same expression. I want to say that the formula looks ill-defined because the same letter represents for two different things. How would I write the plural of the variable *c*? Those are my ideas:

[image]

From the [APA Style blog](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2011/08/the-grammar-of-mathematics-writing-about-variables.html) I gather that “*c*s” is the way to do it, but I am not sure about this. What is the way to go?

Comment: The APA style is not universal; lots of people use *c*'s.

Comment: Consider recasting the sentence: … as each c is a member of a different field.

Comment: Anything but using the apostrophe-S to make a plural. I like @DaleHartleyEmery's rewriting the best, but your fourth and fifth examples work also.

Comment: Consider placing a comma before "as," or replace "as" with "because." http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/80628/use-of-as-instead-of-because

Comment: I recommend "because both c variables are..."

Comment: @PeterShor Using the apostrophe for plural just makes me cringe. People even to that in German although German does not even use the apostrophe for the genitive. Therefore I would like to avoid that although it separates the “c” and the “s” better. Rewording is the way to go, though.

Comment: If it makes you cringe, don't do it. Use the APA style. Or rewrite it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would say

> as the two variables named c are not part of the same field.

Even if technically acceptable, any form of cs is hard to read. Italics applied to only one letter, especially a round one like c are hard to spot.

I changed "both" to "the two" because both invites the reader to consider two items as one, whereas here you want the reader to consider them separately.

Answer (score 3):

Some style guides recommend using an apostrophe, although it might not make logical sense, when speaking of "letters as letters" --

*Can you say your abc's?*

*Mind your p's and q's.*

Comment: The Chicago Manual of Style, to be specific.